# Conflicting .js, checkout not working

Tags: checkout, javascript, conflict

I have my site up and running but I am unable to get the checkout to work and I know why, but I do not know the fix.

```
<?php if($themeConfig->get("enable_ajaxcart")) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var ajaxCart = true;
</script>
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var minicart_url = "<?php echo Mage::helper('ves_tempcp')->getMinicartURL(); ?>";
</script>

<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('calCustom/js/min/ecoWarrior.min.js');?>"></script>
```

The last two scripts are what run my menus however because they come after the getCssJsHtml() ?> it conflicts with my checkout **however** moving them before this stops my Menu from working and gets my checkout to work. I have heard of using the $.noConflict(); but I'm not getting anywhere and cant fathom it out.

The line causing the issue is getSkinUrl('calCustom/js/min/ecoWarrior.min.js');?>">

Can anyone offer any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer, I had to open ecoWarrior.min.js and change all instances of `$` to `jQuery` so noconflict worked fully.

also moving each to above `<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>` stopped other error from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you see in your developer tools console? If you're sure the conflict is in ecoWarrior.min.js then you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('calCustom/js/min/ecoWarrior.min.js');?>"></script>
```

I could give more specific insight if you provided your site's URL or the error that is being thrown by your browser's dev tools.

Comment: That allows the checkout to work perfectly but kills the menu.   
Error showing before your suggestion is>  
 
  
  

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null `ecoWarrior.min.js:1
(anonymous function) ecoWarrior.min.js:1
j jquery.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
m.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
J`

The error showing after the change is>
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `ecoWarrior.min.js:1
(anonymous function) ecoWarrior.min.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):862
(anonymous function) (index):862`

Comment: Are you loading two versions of jQuery?

Comment: @ReidBlomquistI don't think so, I have not set a second one to be called. Just the one I have there in the head.

Comment: You may want to double check by looking in the developer console's resource tab. Here is some more info on the Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429838/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-loading-jquery-min-js

Comment: Oh you might be right, page source shows I am calling two.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecoliving.radiator2.local/js/venustheme/ves_tempcp/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

My menu doesn't work if I dont cal the second one however. Not sure why and only if its where it currently is without a no.conflict affecting it.

Comment: What happens if you take out the first? Or is that a hardcoded link throwing a 404?

Comment: Sorry I took so long. If I take out the first I get a whole load of errors affecting the rest of the jQ on the site. It's called by the <?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?> command.